# Regex expression to find if String contains 1 or more occurencies of number 6

Tags: java

I need to come up with regex expression in Java to find if it contains "6" in the string. At the moment if Im trying to reiterate, my expression counts only first instance of "6", while missing others. Could you please so kind  and help me here?

The following is my code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    BigInteger count = BigInteger.valueOf(0);

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    BigInteger l = s.nextBigInteger();
    BigInteger h = s.nextBigInteger();

    BigInteger i = l;

    for (i = l; (i.compareTo(h) == -1) || (i.compareTo(h) == 0);) {
      String inputAsString = i.toString();
      if (Pattern.matches("[6]+", inputAsString)) {
        count = count.add(BigInteger.ONE);
      }
      i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
    System.out.println("Total of 6s: " + count);
  }
}
```

My code counts only "6", missing "16" if input is 1 and 20.

Comment: You should post your actual code instead of pseudo code. You also need to fix your typo: `int 1 = 0` is not valid of course.

Comment: fixed and updated

Comment: What would `.*6+.*` give you?

Comment: @Matthieu that ".*6+.*" worked - thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Jay. I added an answer to add an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex only matches a single `6`. You have to add the *any number* (`*`) of *any character* (`.`) before and after it:

`if (Pattern.matches(".*[6]+.*", inputAsString))`

Answer (score 0):

You can get number of `6` present in string using `replaceAll` as below
Replace all `6` with "", then find difference of length of input and updated string

```
        String input = "13, 6 and 16";
        int len = input.length();
        String s2 = input.replaceAll("6", "");
        int numOfOccOfSix = len - s2.length();
        
        System.out.println("numOfOccOfSix: "+numOfOccOfSix);
```

Output:

```
numOfOccOfSix: 2
```

Comment: well, I specifically need to use regex for this problem. Thanks for suggestion though.